# Are classes with identical values .equals()?

Tags: java

I'm using Point3D.

I have a list full of Point3Ds. I need to create a NEW Point3D at some point, and check if the list contains it.

Will this list ever contain it as it is technically a different reference/object BUT has identical values?

I understand this is a lack of fundamental knowledge in my Java.

Comment: Looking the [the source code](https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-9-dev-rt/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/geometry/Point3D.java#L399) it appears to compare x,y, and z so different objects with same values will be equal. (Assuming I have the right source code link).

Comment: This official tutorial may help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: *Classes with identical values* - The correct way to say this is "Objects of the same class with identical values". Second: It depends on if the class overrides equals, and then how it overrides equals. But generally, equals is coded to return true if the values are identical

Answer (score 1):

A `List` doesn't care what you put in it - put ten things in, get ten things out.

A `Set` however will generally only have unique values in it (using `.equals()` and `hashCode()` and in some sets other things - e.g. `Comparator`).

Normally I'd say "to the javadoc" however in this case it has a case of cut/paste'ism [from Point3D JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point3D.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

> ```
> equals
>
> public boolean equals(Object obj)
>
> Returns a hash code value for the point.
>
> Overrides:
>     equals in class Object
> Returns:
>     a hash code value for the point.
> ```

So assuming it does what most people expect if you have two points generated with identically valued doubles then yes it'll be as you expect.

HOWEVER, floating point numbers you can easily be "very very close" when you expect to be identical (due to the representation of the value as FP), and remember there are 3 doubles in a Point3D [so 3 potential lots of small error] - so to be safe typically you might decide things are the same within some small distance [see javadoc for distance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point3D.html#distance-javafx.geometry.Point3D-) rather than relying on exact matching.